# Setting Logical Types for AvroIO in Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to serialise classes to Avro in ApacheBeam (on Dataflow).

I have a class I want to write out to Avro, which uses a Joda DateTime property for the logical type timestamp-millis

Outside of Beam, I would map this by annotating the property

```
class Event {
  @AvroSchema("{\"type\": \"long\", \"logicalType\": \"timestamp-millis\"}")
  DateTime dt;
  // ... 
}
```

and then calling

```
// MyTimestampConversion extends TimeConversions.TimestampConversion
// implementing getRecommendedSchema() 
// This is fixed in Avro 1.8.3
ReflectData.get().addLogicalTypeConversion(new MyTimestampConversion());
```

before writing to file.

But, as each AvroIO.Write is distributed, how could I pass the TimestampConversion class to the ReflectData in each process / node and call addLogicalTypeConversion().

This is where the write seems to be called

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/AvroIO.java#L357

As far as I can see all the functionality in AvroIO is static or private and not readily extended? (This might reflect my java, though)

Comment: Not sure if I fully understood your question, but does transforming data to the proper format using a ParDo transform (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#pardo) before writing (using AvroIO) help ?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely work around this by using `long` rather than `DateTime` transforming in a ParDo and outputting a different type in a ParDo. I am really trying to understand if I can get the underlying libraries to do this for me (for example, I can specify custom [de]serialization with Jackson annotations) I will add a more complete example to clarify the errors.